# jquery click does not work with normal function

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

I have a bunch of navigation links inside a list. Each time I click a link I want so show some DIV and hide all the others. It's the common content panel pattern.

I can't make it work by doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

function show_tab(t) {
    jQuery(".tab").hide();
    jQuery(t).toggle();
}

jQuery("#login").click( show_tab("#login_tab") );

jQuery("#projects").click( show_tab("#projects_tab") );

});
</script>
```

But I can make it work just by using an anonymous function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#login").click(function()
{
jQuery(".tab").hide();
jQuery("#login_tab").toggle();
});

jQuery("#projects").click(function()
{
jQuery(".tab").hide();
jQuery("#projects_tab").toggle();
});

});
</script>
```

Can somebody explain why one method works and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `name` of `function` instead of calling it.

```
jQuery("#login").click( show_tab );    
jQuery("#projects").click( show_tab) );
```

You can use the `id` of current element to generate the id of tab in `show_tab`

```
function show_tab()
{    
    jQuery(".tab").hide();  
    jQuery("#" + this.id + "_tab").toggle();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
jQuery("#login").click( show_tab("#login_tab") );
jQuery("#projects").click( show_tab("#projects_tab") );
```

to

```
jQuery("#login").click( function() {
 show_tab("#login_tab");
});
jQuery("#projects").click( function() {
    show_tab("#projects_tab");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this...

```
jQuery("#login").click( show_tab("#login_tab") );
```

it runs `show_tab("#login_tab")` immediately and uses the result as the parameter in the `.click` handler assignment.  If you ever need to pass a function without running it then you must reference it without parenthesis.  You could have done this...

```
jQuery("#login").click( function() {
    show_tab("#login_tab");
} );
```

or even this...

```
jQuery("#login").click( show_login_tab );

function show_login_tab() {
    show_tab("#login_tab");
}
```

That, in essence, is the same as creating the anonymous function, as you did in the working version.